# NHibernate: Logging

Tags: nhibernate, logging

I want to disable logging for one property in nhibernate.
I am logging all the nhibernate queries , but, when i insert a huge binary file, it logs all the bytes. So i want to log all the queries and params except the binary ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, runtime re-configuration of log4net is not possible.  This may help: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html